# Создать программу, которая считывает значение eps (точность вычисления) и выводит y

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ряды

Создать программу, которая считывает значение eps (точность вычисления) и выводит y. Цикл заканчивается, когда новое слагаемое меньше eps.
y = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...

[image]

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    double y = 0;
    double eps;
    cout << "Enter eps: ";
    cin >> eps;
    double i = 2;
    double sum = 0;
    while (y > eps)
    {
        y += 1 / i;
        sum += y;
        i *= 2; 
    }
    cout << "y = " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Так ведь **слагаемое**, а не **сумма** :) Разница понятна? И, кстати, картинки здесь очень не приветствуются. Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, приведя код текстом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, раз все так плохо, что комментарий не помог...

```
int main()
{
    double eps;
    cout << "Enter eps: ";
    cin >> eps;
    double t = 1./2.;
    double sum = t;
    while (t > eps) sum += t /= 2;
    cout << "sum = " << sum << "\n";
}
```